# Alternative for scripting in SVG for using in python

Tags: python, svg, pyqt4, interactive

Is there a way to achieve something similar to scripting in svg file, so it works when it's opened in python gui? I need funcionality similar to one in this [example](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/tooltip), but I am opening my svg in python like this:

```
self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
self.scene().addItem(QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem(QtCore.QFile(pathToMySVG).fileName()))
```

where `self` is `QtGui.QGraphicsView`.

I have also tried without scripting, with these [examples](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-svgint/), but still there is no interactivity.

Any help-examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vicent Actually I've found solution using QGraphicsWebView():

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QGraphicsWebView
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)

    br = QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem("C:\my_interactive_svg.svg").boundingRect()

    webview = QGraphicsWebView()
    webview.load(QtCore.QUrl("C:\my_interactive_svg.svg"))
    webview.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemClipsToShape)
    webview.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.NoCache)
    webview.resize(br.width(), br.height())

    scene.addItem(webview)
    view.resize(br.width()+10, br.height()+10)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works perfect for me (scripting and other stuff).

Only thing that I don't like is that I have to load my svg as QGraphicsSvgItem, because I didn't know other way to get size of my svg. Apparently `webview.size()` does not return expected values.

Comment: Nice to know you've found an alternative solution. Not 100% clean because of the use of `QGraphicsSvgItem` but much better than the `QtSvg` module.

Comment: With that new information I've updated my answer. I think it will be more useful now.

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the [QtSvg module doc](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtsvg.html):

> Qt supports the static features of SVG 1.2 Tiny. ECMA scripts and DOM
>   manipulation are currently not supported.

So if you are going to use the `QtSvg` module you are limited to the static features described [here](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/feature/1.2/#SVG-static).

**Update**:

@Aleksandar after reading your answer I've further investigated in order to remove the dependencies on the `QtSvG` module. The following code achieves just that goal (the trick is to load the image before resizing the container):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QGraphicsWebView
class Scene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QGraphicsScene, self).__init__()
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)

        self.webview = QGraphicsWebView()
        self.webview.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemClipsToShape)
        self.webview.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.NoCache)
        self.addItem(self.webview)

        self.webview.loadFinished.connect(self.svgLoaded)

    def svgLoaded(self):
        frame = self.webview.page().mainFrame()
        fsize = frame.contentsSize()
        self.webview.resize(QtCore.QSizeF(fsize))
        self.view.resize(fsize.width() + 10, fsize.height() + 10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    v = Scene()
    svg = QtCore.QUrl("Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg")
    v.webview.load(svg)
    v.view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code may need some more love but I've no time right now. Anyway I hope it will be useful for you.